# Recommendation system using Deep neural network based on Softmax Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

So, I was going through [Google's DNN based on Softmax Model course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/dnn/softmax) and also gone through sheet [Recommendation system google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/main/ml/recommendation-systems/recommendation-systems.ipynb). I couldn't understand that while building model for Matrix Factorization, embeddings of both user and movies is passed to CFModel class.

```
def build_model(ratings, embedding_dim=3, init_stddev=1.):
  """
  Args:
    ratings: a DataFrame of the ratings
    embedding_dim: the dimension of the embedding vectors.
    init_stddev: float, the standard deviation of the random initial embeddings.
  Returns:
    model: a CFModel.
  """
  # Split the ratings DataFrame into train and test.
  train_ratings, test_ratings = split_dataframe(ratings)
  # SparseTensor representation of the train and test datasets.
  A_train = build_rating_sparse_tensor(train_ratings)
  A_test = build_rating_sparse_tensor(test_ratings)
  # Initialize the embeddings using a normal distribution.
  U = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
      [A_train.dense_shape[0], embedding_dim], stddev=init_stddev))
  V = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
      [A_train.dense_shape[1], embedding_dim], stddev=init_stddev))
  train_loss = sparse_mean_square_error(A_train, U, V)
  test_loss = sparse_mean_square_error(A_test, U, V)
  metrics = {
      'train_error': train_loss,
      'test_error': test_loss
  }
  **embeddings = {
      "user_id": U,
      "movie_id": V
  }**
  **return CFModel(embeddings, train_loss, [metrics])**
```

But while building softmax model, only movie embeddings is passed to CFModel :

```
def build_softmax_model(rated_movies, embedding_cols, hidden_dims):
  """Builds a Softmax model for MovieLens.
  Args:
    rated_movies: DataFrame of traing examples.
    embedding_cols: A dictionary mapping feature names (string) to embedding
      column objects. This will be used in tf.feature_column.input_layer() to
      create the input layer.
    hidden_dims: int list of the dimensions of the hidden layers.
  Returns:
    A CFModel object.
  """
  def create_network(features):
    """Maps input features dictionary to user embeddings.
    Args:
      features: A dictionary of input string tensors.
    Returns:
      outputs: A tensor of shape [batch_size, embedding_dim].
    """
    # Create a bag-of-words embedding for each sparse feature.
    inputs = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, embedding_cols)
    # Hidden layers.
    input_dim = inputs.shape[1].value
    for i, output_dim in enumerate(hidden_dims):
      w = tf.get_variable(
          "hidden%d_w_" % i, shape=[input_dim, output_dim],
          initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(
              stddev=1./np.sqrt(output_dim))) / 10.
      outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, w)
      input_dim = output_dim
      inputs = outputs
    return outputs

  train_rated_movies, test_rated_movies = split_dataframe(rated_movies)
  train_batch = make_batch(train_rated_movies, 200)
  test_batch = make_batch(test_rated_movies, 100)

  with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=False):
    # Train
    train_user_embeddings = create_network(train_batch)
    train_labels = select_random(train_batch["label"])
  with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True):
    # Test
    test_user_embeddings = create_network(test_batch)
    test_labels = select_random(test_batch["label"])
    movie_embeddings = tf.get_variable(
        "input_layer/movie_id_embedding/embedding_weights")

  test_loss = softmax_loss(
      test_user_embeddings, movie_embeddings, test_labels)
  train_loss = softmax_loss(
      train_user_embeddings, movie_embeddings, train_labels)
  _, test_precision_at_10 = tf.metrics.precision_at_k(
      labels=test_labels,
      predictions=tf.matmul(test_user_embeddings, movie_embeddings, transpose_b=True),
      k=10)

  metrics = (
      {"train_loss": train_loss, "test_loss": test_loss},
      {"test_precision_at_10": test_precision_at_10}
  )
  **embeddings = {"movie_id": movie_embeddings}
  return CFModel(embeddings, train_loss, metrics)**
```

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: side note: "create_network" is missing activatino functions, this will always create a deep **linear** model (no matter how many hidden layers are added)

Comment: @lejlot how to add activation functions? like for softmax model.

Comment: If it was supposed to be an MLP `outputs = tf.matmul(inputs, w)` should be `outputs = tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(inputs), w) + b`, and `b` should be a new variable of size `[output_dim]`

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking over the notebook to see what I could find.
They explain at the beginning of each section what each model is meant to do:

> [image]

The goal of **Matrix Factorization** is to create a recommender system. [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/matrix-factorization) article here explains the theory behind it:

> **4.3 Matrix factorization**
> Matrix factorization techniques (Lee and Seung, 2000; Salakhutdinov and Mnih, 2008) are commonly considered when dealing with recommendation systems. The scenario corresponds to a group of m entities mapping to a group of n other entities. A very common example is the movie recommendation for users. In this case the task is to determine proximity and distance between a movie and a user as if both are same type of entities.

With regards to softmax the notebook says:

> VI. **Softmax model**
> In this section, we will train a simple softmax model that predicts whether a given user has rated a movie.
> ...
> The model will take as input a feature vector  x  representing the list of movies the user has rated. We start from the ratings DataFrame, which we group by user_id.

With the **softmax** model, the goal is predict a probability of falling into some class, and according to the [course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/dnn/softmax)

> Deep Neural Network Models
> The previous section showed you how to use matrix factorization to learn embeddings. Some limitations of matrix factorization include:

> The difficulty of using side features (that is, any features beyond the query ID/item ID). As a result, the model can only be queried with a user or item present in the training set.
> Relevance of recommendations. As you saw in the first Colab, popular items tend to be recommended for everyone, especially when using dot product as a similarity measure. It is better to capture specific user interests.
> Deep neural network (DNN) models can address these limitations of matrix factorization. DNNs can easily incorporate query features and item features (due to the flexibility of the input layer of the network), which can help capture the specific interests of a user and improve the relevance of recommendations.
> **Softmax DNN for Recommendation**
> One possible DNN model is softmax, which treats the problem as a multiclass prediction problem in which:
> The input is the user query.
> The output is a probability vector with size equal to the number of items in the corpus, representing the probability to interact with each item; for example, the probability to click on or watch a YouTube video.
> Input
> The input to a DNN can include:
> dense features (for example, watch time and time since last watch)
> sparse features (for example, watch history and country)
> Unlike the matrix factorization approach, you can add side features such as age or country. We’ll denote the input vector by x.

The general idea for each of these models is to produce a similarity score (distance) for each movie that can then be used for recommendations.
[image]

You can see that when they build the softmax model they are passing rated_movies, which is a dataframe of the movie ratings by the users.

```
def build_softmax_model(rated_movies, embedding_cols, hidden_dims):
  """Builds a Softmax model for MovieLens..."""
```

In both methods they are using user ratings to make their similarity scores.
I hope this helps.

Comment: In the same [course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/dnn/retrieval) it is saying to get user recommendation, we can compute query embedding by running the network on feature vector x. So to get embedding of particular user, should I pass single feature in create_network() and its output would be user_embedding of that user? Then I can check which movie embedding is more closer to this user?